# VB.Net Excel Addin, how to write data to specific worksheet by name?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

So here's the problem I have. I am converting an old Excel macro into an excel add in so I can share it easier with my coworkers. I am new to VB.net but I'm doing what I can so please go easy on me.

I have a Windows form that allows a user to enter data and when they hit the enter data button the data is supposed to go form the form to a specific worksheet. The code is as follows:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form_CutListEntry

    Dim xApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim wss As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet


    Private Sub Btn_InsertJobInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_InsertJobInfo.Click
        wss = xApp.Worksheets("Job Info")

        'Check that all data is entered
        If Trim(TxtBx_CustomerName.Text) = "" Then
            TxtBx_CustomerName.Focus()
            MsgBox("Please enter a Customer Name")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Trim(TxtBx_OrderNum.Text) = "" Then
            TxtBx_OrderNum.Focus()
            MsgBox("Please enter an Order Number")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Trim(TxtBx_CutlistAuthor.Text) = "" Then
            TxtBx_CutlistAuthor.Focus()
            MsgBox("Please enter your initials")
            Exit Sub
        End If

       'Write data to excel worksheet. 
        wss.Cells(3, 1) = "Customer Name: " + TxtBx_CustomerName.Text
        wss.Cells(4, 1) = "Order Number: " + TxtBx_OrderNum.Text
        wss.Cells(5, 1) = "Todays Date: " + TxtBx_TodaysDate.Text
        wss.Cells(6, 1) = "Cutting List Prepared By: " + TxtBx_CutlistAuthor.Text

        Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

(Note I took out the comments and some extra parts that aren't pertinent so the detailed error message below has the wrong line numbers)

I can open the windows form just fine from excel, but when I enter some data and click enter data this happens:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Toms CutList Maker.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

On this line:

```
wss = xApp.Worksheets("Job Info")
```

Any chance anyone can point me in the write direction with this?

Here is the full error details if someone is interested:

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.get_Worksheets()
       at Toms_CutList_Maker.Form_CutListEntry.Btn_InsertJobInfo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\tom\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Toms CutList Maker\Toms CutList Maker\CutList Entry.vb:line 15
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: the `Worksheet Object` is not a member of the `Excel Application Object`, but it is a member of the `Workbook Object`, which is a member the of `Excel Application Object`. So first, set the `Workbook`, then set the `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer directly to a worksheet from the Excel Application. The worksheets collection is part of the Workbook object. The Workbooks Collection is part of the Application Object.

Try this instead:

```
Dim xApp As New Excel.Application 
Dim wss As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook

....

wb = xApp.Workbooks("My Workbook.xlsx") 'replace with your workbook name and proper file extension
wss = wb.Worksheets("Job Info")
```

Comment: Alrighty so I tried this and this is how I wrote it:  'wb = xApp.Workbooks("CUTLISTMAKER")
        wss = wb.Worksheets("Job Info")' For whatever reason I get  similar error but it says invalid index. I also tried using wb = xApp.ActiveWorkbook and that too gives me an error.

Comment: try "CUTLISTMAKER.xlsx" or whatever the appropriate file extension is for your file

Comment: Get the same error still unfortunately, the error is not on the Job Info line its on the new wb=xApp.Workbooks line. . Honestly I would rather have it work with ActiveWorkbook if I could cause the name of the workbook could change. If I change it to this: wb = xApp.ActiveWorkbook then I get a  'System.NullReferenceException' error on the wss=wb.Worksheets("Job Info") line

Comment: how about `wb = ThisApplication.Workbooks("CUTLISTMAKER.xlsx")`

Comment: tells me "ThisApplication" is not declared, I could go ahead and declare it but then we'd be back at square one right? or is there a different way to declare it?

Comment: wait, I think I see now.... Your problem is actually here `Dim xApp As New Excel.Application` You are telling your code to create a **New** Excel instance, then trying to reference the workbook in the existing instance. Try this: `Dim xApp as Excel.Application` then `xApp = GetObject("Excel.Application","")` then stick with the workbook and worksheet reference as I stated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95865/discussion-between-tom-and-scott-holtzman).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error straight from Excel.
I have done the same exact thing, and this is what I have got:

```
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(Application.StartupPath + "\My Workbook.xlsx")
xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add("Job Info")
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("JobInfo")
```

Make sure the workbook that you're trying to open exists.